# Separating distinct lines in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, intersection, linestring

I have a table of linestring segments in Postgis. These segments make up distinct non-intersecting lines as shown by the diagram. To add confusion the direction of the linestrings are not uniform.

I want to create a simple set of linestrings that are uniformly joined in a single direction, this will enable me to shorten them if required using ST_LineInterpolate().

So, looking at the diagram you can see three lines which is what I want to get out of the query. I tried a recursive query but this ran forever on a table of only 10 linestrings:-

```
WITH RECURSIVE line_join(ogc_fid,wkb_geometry) AS (

 SELECT ogc_fid, wkb_geometry FROM TABLE.tll_lines_selected WHERE ogc_fid=47
UNION ALL
     SELECT n.ogc_fid, n.wkb_geometry FROM TABLE.tll_lines_selected n, line_join lj
     WHERE ST_Intersects(n.wkb_geometry,lj.wkb_geometry)

) SELECT ogc_fid FROM line_join;
```

Therefore I think something is not right. Is there a better strategy?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made progress on this last night thanks to the answer here [Select the lines that form a ring in postgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32224/select-the-lines-that-form-a-ring-in-postgis)

```
WITH RECURSIVE merge_lines(ogc_fid, wkb_geometry, path, merged) AS 
(
    SELECT ls.ogc_fid, ls.wkb_geometry, array[ls.ogc_fid],ST_LineMerge(ls.wkb_geometry) FROM TABLE.tll_lines_selected AS ls

UNION ALL

    SELECT ls.ogc_fid, ls.wkb_geometry, path || ls.ogc_fid,(ST_Dump(ST_LineMerge(ST_Collect(ls.wkb_geometry, merged)))).geom
    FROM merge_lines, TABLE.tll_lines_selected AS ls
    WHERE ls.ogc_fid != ALL(path) AND ST_Touches(ls.wkb_geometry, merged)


) 
SELECT DISTINCT (array_sort(path))[1] as first, array_length(path,1) as plen, array_sort(path) as members FROM merge_lines GROUP BY first,plen,members ORDER BY plen DESC
```

They key was passing the feature id back into the recursion in an array to prevent an infinite loop. The next step is to choose the longest array for a given starting ID